# Typescript: Getting intellisense from local AMD modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm using knockout components where I basically have a ts file for each component. These files are used to generate amd files. For each view model, an interface has been created for the fields. How do I get this to show in an instance where I'm using one component in another and want intellisense with respect to the fields.

Secondly, I'm using require js which has a require.config.js file. In this files, in the path property, I can declare modules and a shorter name(eg. `db: "../../files/db"`). How do I get intellisense support for this imported modules using (`import db = require("db")`). They all appear as any and any interfaces declare in these modules do not show at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can declare modules and a shorter name(eg. db: "../../files/db"). How do I get intellisense support for this imported modules using (import db = require("db")).

Your best bet is to use transforms https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/blob/master/README.md#transforms

> For each view model, an interface has been created for the fields.

Move these into a .d.ts file and ///reference this file when you want to use them.

Comment: I ended using the second option where the interfaces were moved to the external file. I was thinking VS will get the right files but I guess this solution works too. Thanks.